# How to set gravity of row in KeyBoardView in android?

Tags: java, android, layout, keyboard, android-keypad

I am working to make a custom keyboard with android `KeyboardView` [android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView]. Everything works fine except when I am trying to reduce the width of the key.

**The Problem is: Here I can't make the bottom row gravity to center**

[image]

**The Code Behind this is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="60dp">


    <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
        <Key android:keyLabel="," android:keyWidth="5%p"  android:codes="44"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="/" android:keyWidth="5%p"  android:codes="47"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="SPACE" android:keyWidth="40%p" android:isRepeatable="true" android:codes="32"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="DEL" android:keyWidth="10%p" android:isRepeatable="true" android:codes="-5"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="DONE" android:keyWidth="10%p"  android:codes="-4"/>
    </Row>

</Keyboard>
```

**So, Is there Any way to make this row gravity to center?**

Comment: why your space is smaller? make it match parent

Comment: @UsamaAltaf Thats not the solution! it would take the entire row then!

Comment: Set ```android:gravity="center"``` in your ```android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView``` layout.

Comment: @Darkman That Does not work. already tried

Comment: @EmonHossainMunna Have you found any solution to this issue?

Comment: @venkat yes i managed to solve that

Comment: Can you please share an answer regarding your solution? What was the issue and how did you solve it? I am facing a similar issue in spite of setting android:horizontalGap value.